# Convert Latin Unicode characters to Japanese counterparts

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, unicode

Translating Unicode characters to their Latin counterparts in for comparison can be achieved with Normalization. However, if I want to go from the standard 'A' to 'Ａ' (Japanese 0xEF,0xBC,0xA1)?
Is there a way to transliterate this using the Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` . But in .Net Core, this assembly only for 3.0 up.
2. like this code

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Narrow to Wide: " + Strings.StrConv("ABCDEFG", VbStrConv.Wide, 0));
            // output Narrow to Wide: ＡＢＣＤＥＦＧ
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a VB lib isn't really my thing, but that helped me to work around my problem :)